# How to pass these data out of this block?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am trying to read some json format rest-api which is in my local host and then show their points on my google map, but there is a problem because I cannot get the latitude and longitude out of the getJSON block, I am new in JavaScript and rest-api.
please help me and feel free to ask any question, BTW this is my code:

```
<script>
var b=true;
var lon=0.0;
var lat=0.0;
var center=null;
function myMap() {

$.getJSON('http://localhost:4567/game-net/name/megafun', function(data) {

    console.log(data);
    lat+=data[0].lattitude;
    lon+=data[0].longtitude;
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lon);
    center= new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    console.log(center);
});
console.log(lat);//this is 0 and if I dont initialize by zero will be undefined
console.log(center);
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(35.741635,51.448145);
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 15};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the code in the callback is executed *after* the code where you work with google maps. `$.ajax` is an asynchronous operation, which means that it starts, but does not finish yet by the time `console.log` and further operations launch.
Look at the following example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("foo");
}, 1000);
console.log("bar");
```

In this snippet,

1.The timer is set
 2. Further code runs, and "bar", is loged
 3. Callback fires, and "foo" is loged.

In your case,

1. Client starts connecting to the server
2. Some data are loged into console, all the google maps code is run
3. Only after that, the response from server is delivered.

*So the simplest solution is just to put the rest of the code into the callback function.*

But overusing callbacks can make your code ugly and lead to callback hell, so there are some alternatives in javascript to do it in a more beautiful way, but they can seem a bit sophisticated at the first glance. Please don’t hesitate to ask if you need any additional information.

You can use async functions instead of callbacks. Your code will still be asynchronous but it will look as if it were synchronous and will be more readable. First, define your function as **async**: `async function myMap() {…}`.

Second, use [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of `$.ajax`, and use the **await** keyword.

```
var unparsedData = await fetch(“your url here”);  // the engine will stop execution here and will wait for the server to respond
var data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data); // your data is now here
```

Some links:

[Here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) you can find an explanation of *asynchrony* in javascript, some examples of *callback hell* and some info about *promises*.

[Here](https://javascript.info/async) comes a very good guide about Promises and async-await.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, what are the alternative ways ?

Comment: btw another question I think myMap() is my callback function since :
<script src=".....&callback=myMap"></script>

Comment: @forsakenmystery just updated the answer

Comment: @forsakenmystery Yes, myMap is a callback which is fired on script load. And it launches an ajax request and sets up another callback to run when it is executed. That’s how javascript works. Most of i/o operations are async and thus require callbacks. Events require callbacks as well.

Comment: wow thank you <3 It helped and I am going to read what are these concepts, God bless you happy new year

Comment: @forsakenmystery I also highly recommend reading [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6465846)